# Textbox getting disabled after zooming the page

Tags: html, internet-explorer, zooming

I have an HTML page with a number of textboxes. When someone zoom the page the textbox gets disabled.

The problem is only occurring in **desktop IE** version. I am unable to understand what can be the issue.

The behavior is only occurring in IE

Comment: Does this behaviour occur in mobile devices or desktop browsers ?

Comment: + Do you use any UI frameworks like `bootstrap` etc?

Comment: The behavior is only happening in IE

Comment: Can you also answer to @NikhilNanjappa 's question?

Comment: the problem is only occurring in Desktop IE version

Comment: We are not using any framework